# Multiple notifyListeners in flutter ChangeNotifier trigger only one build in widget

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-change-notifier, flutter-change-notifier-provider

I have Flutter app with simple Provider and Consumer flow `class SomeProvider with ChangeNotifier`. My `SubscriptionProvider` has next methods:

```
 methodA() async {
    isLoading = true;
    data = {};

    notifyListeners();

    await Future.delayed(Duration.zero, otherMethod);

    methodB();
  }

  methodB() {
    isLoading = false;
    data = {
 
    notifyListeners();
  }
```

Widget Code:

```
Consumer<SomeProvider>(
  builder: (ctx, someProvider, _) {
    if (someProvider.isLoading) {
      return WidgetC();
    }


    return WidgetD();
  }
)
```

My problem is that when `methodA` is called `build` runs only once. On the other hand if I run `await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 2), otherMethod);` instead of `await Future.delayed(Duration.zero, otherMethod);` everything works fine and I have two builds. Are there any ways to perform `build` every time I call `notifyListeners` in provider.

Comment: I'm not sure how this works, but I found the documentation here https://pub.dev/documentation/provider/latest/provider/Consumer-class.html

Comment: @FelipeMorschel I understand how Consumer works. My question is "Why does my Consumer build is called only once when it should run twice"

Comment: Are you actually calling the methods that notify the Consumer?

Comment: @FelipeMorschel, sure, I call it in different Widget